# Access placeholders in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, placeholder

I need to create the names of my placeholders dynamically in a loop in C# but I don't know how i can get the right name.

The placeholders are set in the aspx page and with `currMaxValues` is the max. number of Placeholders set.

My current markup:

```
const int currMaxValues = 6;

        for (int i = 0; i < currMaxValues; i ++)
        {
            //new placeholdernames
            string currPlaceholderTime = "placeholderTime" + i;
            string currPlaceholderMore = "placeholderZusatz" + i;
            string currPlaceholderIco = "placeholderIco" + i;
            string currPlaceholderTemp = "placeholderTemp" + i;

            //elements for placeholders
            Label time = null;
            Label more = null;
            Image img = null;
            Label temp = null;

            //built the stuff for the placeholders
            DateTime currTime = DateTime.Now;
            int hour = currTime.Hour;
            time.Text = hour.ToString();

            //(PlaceHolder)currPlaceholderTime.Controls.add(time);
        }
```

Is it possible to use the name of the Placholder that I created at the beginning of the loop to access the controls?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use FindControl function to find a control with dynamic id as below

```
FindControl("controlname")
```

In your case you need to change the code as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < currMaxValues; i ++)
        {
            //new placeholdernames
            string currPlaceholderTime = "placeholderTime" + i;
            string currPlaceholderMore = "placeholderZusatz" + i;
            string currPlaceholderIco = "placeholderIco" + i;
            string currPlaceholderTemp = "placeholderTemp" + i;

            //elements for placeholders
            Label time = null;
            Label more = null;
            Image img = null;
            Label temp = null;

            //built the stuff for the placeholders
            DateTime currTime = DateTime.Now;
            int hour = currTime.Hour;
            time.Text = hour.ToString();

            Placeholder placeHolderTime = FindControl(currPlaceholderTime) as PlaceHolder;
            placeHolderTime.Controls.Add(time);

            //(PlaceHolder)currPlaceholderTime.Controls.add(time);
        }
```

However note that, the above code works only if your page not under master page  or the placeholders are directly under the main page.
If you are not able find with the above code, you need to have a function like below, to find the control hierarchically.

```
private Control FindControl(Control rootControl, string controlID)
  {
   if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

   foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
   {
    Control controlToReturn =
     FindControl(controlToSearch, controlID);
    if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
   }
   return null;
  }
```

Then you can call the above function using the following code to find the placeholders

```
Placeholder placeHolderTime = FindControl(this,currPlaceholderTime) as PlaceHolder;
```